# Неправильная работа php date_create_from_format( )

Tags: php

Когда я запускаю такой скрипт:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:m:s', '08/01/2017 15:00:00');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

Я получаю 2016-12-08 15:12:00.
Почему не 2017-01-08 15:00:00??
Что я делаю неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` - месяц,
`i`-минуты, т.е. правильно не `H:m:s`, а `H:i:s`:

```
$date = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', '08/01/2017 15:00:00');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Ах дааа, совсем не обратил внимания. Иногда перепутаю m и i. Спасибо